# When to use "verb + ed" not for the past but for the future?

Tags: present-perfect, past-participles

I get always confused with the possibility to use `verb + ed` for the future. The text I'm writing brings the same problem and I'm not sure if I do a mistake if I write:

> "Once we ***receive*** and ***review*** it, we will confirm your order by e-mail."

rather than

> "Once we ***received*** and ***reviewed*** it, we will confirm your order by e-mail."

Which one is correct - can anyone please explain me the rule of how to use `verb+ed` in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first version is acceptable, but the second is not.

I think what may be confusing you is the fact that regular verbs in English use the ***-ed*** form for two different entities:

- The **simple past** tense ...

  > *We **received** your order yesterday*.
- The **past participle**, which is used with the auxiliary *have* in **perfect** constructions:

  > *We **have received** your order and will ship today.*

In the sentence you are trying to write, the subordinate clause beginning *once* is related to the main clause *we will confirm...*, but it is not expressed with a future construction because it is an event which much occur *before* the action of the main clause. Consequently you may use either the **simple present** tense, as in your first example, or a **present perfect** construction:

> Once we ***have received and reviewed*** it, we will confirm your order by e-mail.

Comment: @StoneyB, Can we say that present perfect sounds a little more formal in this example?

Comment: @ArmanMcHitarian e h . . . Not really. A little more precise, perhaps: it says unambiguously that we won't confirm your order until *after* we finish receiving and reviewing it. But there's little or no room for ambiguity in this case.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thanks for the quick reply. One more thing, would you prefer one over the other in formal text, such as emails to your customers or some sort of user-manual or documentation?

Comment: @ArmanMcHitarian In an email, it depends on why I'm telling the customer all this. In a manual I'd probably tell the user something like "As soon as you get the order review it and send the customer a confirmation if everything's in order."